# Why do i get a segmentation fault when I try to enter "x" to exit my program

Tags: c++

> the  function DataDisplayAndSearch for some reason causes a segmentation fault  when i enter "x" to exit the program. I have tried debugging and cannot figure out what the problem could be. This is homework

```
string DataDisplayAndSearch (int customerCount, string ssn[])
{
    //local variables
    int index;
    int count;
    int numberLen;
    int numberLocation = NOT_FOUND;
    int high;
    int low;
    int middle;
    bool invalidNumber = false;
    string choice;

    cout << " Social Security Numbers on file are:" << endl;

    for (index = 0; index < customerCount; index++)
    {
        cout << " " << ssn[index] << " ";
    }
    do
    {
        cout << endl << endl << " Enter SSN to find (or X to exit):";
        invalidNumber = false;
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice != EXIT && choice != EXIT1)
        {
            numberLen = choice.length();

            if (numberLen < LENGTH || numberLen > LENGTH) 
            {
                invalidNumber = true;
            }

            for (count = 0; count < LENGTH; count++)
            {
                if (isprint(choice[count]));
                else
                {
                    invalidNumber = true;
                }
            }

            if (choice[IDX2] != DASH || choice[IDX5] != DASH)
            {
                invalidNumber = true;
            }

            low = 0;
            high = customerCount - 1;

            while ((low <= high) && (numberLocation == NOT_FOUND))
            {
                middle = (low + high) / 2;

                if (choice > ssn[middle])
                {
                    high = middle - 1;
                }
                else if (choice < ssn[middle])
                {
                    low = middle + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    numberLocation = middle;
                }
            }

            if (numberLocation == NOT_FOUND)
            {
                cout << " Error!! Please enter a valid SSN." << endl;
            }

            if (invalidNumber)
            {
                cout << " Input dashes and digits " << choice << " are formatted."
                     << " SSN must be exactly 11 characters long, formatted as:"
                     << " ###-##-###" << endl;
            }

        } //end of if

    } while (((invalidNumber) && (choice != EXIT && choice != EXIT1 ) && (numberLocation == NOT_FOUND)));
}
```

Comment: You didn't show enough code, but I'd suspect you are missing a `return` statement at the end of the function.

Comment: Hard to say since you didn't post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but `if (isprint(choice[count]));` might be accessing out of bounds when `choice` only has one character in it

Comment: I too suspect crash is probably because of this line if (isprint(choice[count]))

Comment: As @SridharDD said - try replacing `count < LENGTH` with `count < numberLen`.

Comment: When the `choice` is **bigger** than the middle item you shrink the search range to the **lower** part. Is your `ssn` array sorted in descending order...?

Answer (score 0):

When the outer loop exits for any reason, including `choice == EXIT`, the function exits without providing a return value of type `string`. The caller then attempts to use a non-existent `string` object, hence the crash.

Crossing the closing brace of a function with a non-`void` return type is *undefined behavior*. It may crash, but might not crash every time. Your compiler might warn you about things like this if you can enable its warning feature, such as by `-Wall` on the command line.